# Tweaking Solr scoring function

Tags: solr, lucene

In Solr 6.0.0, I want to tweak the scoring based on which field matches (in indexing and searching xml files), do I have to override my own similarity class ?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use a custom Similarity, that's more useful for changing things like how term popularity effects score. Simply ranking different fields differently is typically what you use score boosts for.

```
q=foo:something^100 OR bar:something^10
```

I recommend reading https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ and maybe take a look at the dismax query parser, which has a convenient notation for that kind of thing. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser (and the "qf" parameter)